# Point group symmetry: difference between $C_6$ and $C_{6v}$

Tags: symmetry, group-theory, crystals

I am having trouble understanding the difference between $C_6$ and $C_{6v}$ symmetry: why don't all structures with $C_6$ symmetry also have $C_{6v}$ symmetry? Does $C_6$ only apply to 2D structures? If someone could point me to a visualization of the difference between these 2 symmetries, that would be very helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both $C_n$ and $C_{nv}$ point groups have an n-fold symmetry axis, but $C_{nv}$, in addition to that, also has $n$ *vertical* mirror planes, i.e., mirror planes containing the $C_n$ axis. The point symmetries of a regular hexagonal pyramid correspond to $C_{nv}$. Any decoration preserving the $C_6$ axis but destroying the $6$ mirror reflection planes corresponds to $C_6$ symmetry. An example is in the following two animated gifs.

[image: Example of a set of points with C_6v symmetry]
Example of a set of points with $C_{6v}$ symmetry

[image: Example of a set of points with C_6 symmetry]
Example of a set of points with $C_{6}$ symmetry

2D structures do not have out-of-plane symmetries. Therefore, no $C_{6v}$ symmetry group exists. Just $C_{6}$.